# Bind a css class name to a viewmodel with knockoutjs

Tags: knockout.js

I am doing this css binding:

```
css: { greenBorder: hasGreenBorder, whiteBorder: hasWhiteBorder, blackBorder: hasBlackBorder }
```

This works but why should my viewmodel return not just the css class name like .whiteBorder or .blackBorder.

because my logic is that from all 3 has-Variables there can only be one true the others are always false.

I think there must be a better way just to apply the class name and put this logic which classname to choose in my viewmodel, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The proper way**

The [class binding](https://github.com/knockout/knockout/wiki/Bindings---class) is what you are looking for.

> This binding allows you set an arbitrary css class for an element. It
>   requires jQuery.

Usage :

```
<div data-bind="class: single">Single Observable Class</div>
<div data-bind="class: multiple">Multiple Observable Classes</div>



var vm = {
    single: ko.observable("red"),
    multiple: ko.observableArray(["blue","small"])
};
vm.change = function () {
    vm.single(vm.single() === "red" ? "black" : "red");

    if (vm.multiple.indexOf("small") > -1) {
        vm.multiple.remove("small");
        vm.multiple.push("big");
    } else {
        vm.multiple.remove("big");
        vm.multiple.push("small");
    }    
};
```

I hope it helps

Comment: The proper way? What is wrong about: data-bind="attr: { class: yourClass }" ?

Comment: It is error prone because attr: { class: yourClass } deletes the previous content of the class attribute.
So when you write this :
<div class="deletedClass" data-bind="attr: { class: yourClass }" />
The deletedClass class will disappear.

Comment: This is ok in general, but I do not have described that scenario ;-)

Answer (score 7):

You can use the [attr](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/attr-binding.html) binding.

```
data-bind="attr: { class: yourClass }"
```

Comment: Is this new in knockout 2.2.0 that I can bind a class as attribute?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use an observable or computed variable as a class name, look at this sample code taken from the [Knockout documentation](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/css-binding.html):

```
<div data-bind="css: profitStatus">
   Profit Information
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var viewModel = {
        currentProfit: ko.observable(150000)
    };

    // Evalutes to a positive value, so initially we apply the "profitPositive" class
    viewModel.profitStatus = ko.computed(function() {
        return this.currentProfit() < 0 ? "profitWarning" : "profitPositive";
    }, viewModel);

    // Causes the "profitPositive" class to be removed and "profitWarning" class to be added
    viewModel.currentProfit(-50);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You *can* use the `attr` binding to set the class (as suggested by @david.s) but when I have this type of logic I tend to put it in a custom `bindingHandler`.

I would make the viewModel expose some state information that would determine (in this case) border color but is not directly tied to a class:

```
this.state = ko.observable("complete"); //complete, pending, or cancelled (for example)
```

I would then use a binding handler to map this onto classes

```
ko.bindingHandlers.stateStyle = {
    update: function(element, valueAccessor) {
        var state = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());

        if (state === "completed") {
            $(element).addClass("hasGreenBorder"); //again, just an example
        }
        else if (state === "pending") {
            //etc
        }
    }
}
```

Then I would use the new binding on the element

```
<div data-bind="stateStyle: state"></div>
```

This approach means that the view model is not directly referencing css classes (which feels wrong to me) and that the logic for `state1 => green border` is not defined in an inline binding in the view.

Comment: A viewmodel holds the model for the view and this is the colors etc... Why should it be wrong that a viewmodel knows a border color like black or .blackBorder? There is no advantage in having the class name in the custom binding. A viewmodel is a converter (josh smith) on steroids what you do is conversion. I do not need a binding for this.